# How to transpose correctly?

Tags: excel, vba

My task is to create a function with two input of vector and one optional, which is a boolean.
The function finds out the lowest difference in absolute value between the elements of the two inputs.
Return value is a vector with two elements:
first is the i index of the founded number in the first array
second is the j index of the founded number in the second array

if the optional input true then giving it back in column vector, if false then in row vector. 
My code do not contains the optional input yet, and transpose does not work well.

```
Function Matrix(AArray As Variant, BArray As Variant) As Variant


Dim actualValue As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

Dim iToFind As Integer
Dim jToFind As Integer

Dim minimum As Integer

minimum = AArray(1) - BArray(1)
For i = 1 To AArray.Count
    For j = 1 To BArray.Count

        actualValue = AArray(i) - BArray(j)
        If actualValue < minimum Then
        iToFind = i
        jToFind = j
        minimum = actualValue
        End If
Next j
j = 1
Next i

Dim Result As Variant
Result = Array(iToFind, jToFind)
Matrix = Application.Transpose(Result)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not really sure what exactly your question was, but I will just assume you were looking for a way to finish your function.

Anyways, first of all, setting j=1 is not necessary, since it will always start from 1 once the inner loop has finished one iteration. Next, you are not computing an absolute distance, but rather just the difference, which will give you wrong results with negative numbers etc.

```
Function Matrix(AArray As Variant, BArray As Variant, Optional asRow As Boolean = True)
Dim actualValue As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim iToFind As Integer
Dim jToFind As Integer
Dim minimum As Integer

minimum = Abs(AArray(1) - BArray(1))
For i = 1 To AArray.Count
    For j = 1 To BArray.Count
        actualValue = Abs(AArray(i) - BArray(j))
        If actualValue < minimum Then
        iToFind = i
        jToFind = j
        minimum = actualValue
        End If
    Next j
Next i

If asRow = True Then
    Matrix = Array(iToFind, jToFind)
Else
    Matrix = Application.Transpose(Array(iToFind, jToFind))
End If
End Function
```

All you need to do now, is select two cells (row or column, you need to specify with thrid paramter) and type in the formula. Then hit CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER and you should get your solution.

Comment: I get an error message "the formula contains unrecognized text" as trying it with 2 cell range with int numbers as input.

Comment: Works just fine for me, could you maybe edit your question with a minimum reproducible example?

Comment: I have no idea why, but in a new form it works. Sorry and thanks!